# ¿Cómo añadir Graphics a un evento de botón?

Tags: java, eventos

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz.length; j++) {
                Color color = null;
                switch(matriz[i][j]){
                    case 0: color = Color.WHITE;
                    case 1: color = Color.RED;
                    case 3: color = Color.GREEN;
                }
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(30*i, 30*j, 30, 30);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(30*i, 30*j, 30, 30);
            }
        }
    }
```

El cual dibuja una matriz sobre un JPanel.

Pero lo que necesito es que ese método esté dentro de un evento de un botón, y se ejecute al pulsarlo.

```
private void btnPruebaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {...}
```

Ya que por el momento, me funcionaba tal cual está (mostrándolo en el JPanel principal) pero ahora necesito mostrarlo en un JDialog.

¿Cómo puedo implementar ese método de Graphics para añadirlo al evento y mostrarlo en el JDialog?

Comment: El método `paint` se ejecuta cada vez que el componente debe ser redibujado. Si no quieres que se ejecute el código que pusiste adentro, ponlo dentro de un `if` que verifique el valor de alguna variable y cuando presiones el botón modifica esa variable para que se cumpla la condición del `if`.

Comment: Es que necesito que ese bloque de Graphics sea ejecutado desde el evento del botón.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres pero el método `paint` "se ejecuta solo". Lo que puedes hacer es condicionar el bloque de código que no quieres que se ejecute hasta que presiones el botón.

Comment: Intentaré moviendo paint a una nueva clase, y añadir un objeto nuevo de la clase añadiéndolo a un JPanel.